# Shopify plugin Script Editor - undefined method

Tags: ruby, shopify, shopify-app

I am working in **Shopify** with a plugin called **Script Editor** and it is giving an error: 
`undefined method 'end_with?' for nil`. 
My syntax for Ruby is not so great and wanted to ask for help on how to exit the command if an empty or non existent email from customer on this line: `if customer && customer.email.end_with?("@mycompany.com")`

Here's the code in **Ruby**:

```
Input.cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
  next if line_item.variant.product.gift_card?
  discount = 1

  customer = Input.cart.customer
  if customer && customer.email.end_with?("@mycompany.com") //<< needs a better condition
    message = "Lorem Ipsum"
    discount = 0.2
  end
  next unless discount < 1
  
  line_item.change_line_price(
    line_item.line_price * discount,
    message: message,
  )
end

Output.cart = Input.cart
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `customer.email` is `nil` rather than a string. You could either explicitly check: `not customer.email.nil?` or catch the exception and handle it.

Comment: @Chris when i changed this line to `if not customer.email.nil? && customer.email.end_with?("@mycompany.com")` I get an error `undefined method 'email' for nil`

Comment: You can use ruby's safe navigation operator `&.`. `if customer&.email&.ends_with?("@mycompany.com")`. This will satisfy your condition.

Comment: @the_spectator i get an error `undefined method 'ends_with' for "test@mycompany.com"`, changed ending to `end_with` (no 's') and it works

Comment: @tq There was a typo in my comment, it should be `end_with?("@mycompany.com")` instead of `ends_with?("@mycompany.com")`. Notice extra `s` in later.

Comment: @tq if the above solution works for you, should I submit it as answer?

Comment: @the_spectator would you like to write that so you can get credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ruby's safe navigation operator `&.'.

```rb
Input.cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
  next if line_item.variant.product.gift_card?
  discount = 1

  customer = Input.cart.customer
  if customer&.email&.end_with?("@mycompany.com")
    message = "Lorem Ipsum"
    discount = 0.2
  end
  next unless discount < 1
  
  line_item.change_line_price(
    line_item.line_price * discount,
    message: message,
  )
end

Output.cart = Input.cart
```

From [doc's](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html):

`&.`, called “safe navigation operator”, allows to skip method call when receiver is nil. It returns nil and doesn't evaluate method's arguments if the call is skipped.

Reference: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html